# Knockout: remove select options from array when already in use

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, knockout.js

I have a little knockout form which I am able to duplicate using a button to allow multiple sets of data to be provided.

However, each value for the 'sample rate' select can only be used once. For example, the first form by default is set to `192000`. So when I click `'add srate element'` the form that is generated should not include `192000` as an option in the `Sample rate` drop-down.

Obviously if the `Sample rate` for the first form is set to something else, that value should be removed for the second form, and so on.

How do I remove the already-selected `Sample rate` from the array when a new form is added, so that it is not available in further copies of the form? It is even possible, given the structure of the view model?

There's a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3lliot/x3cg131g/

There's a bit of logic included already to prevent more than 6 forms.

Any tips will be appreciated ...

**Html code:**

```
<body>
   <ul data-bind="foreach: forms">
      <li>
         <!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->
         <p><span style="color:#AB0002">Sample rate element <span data-bind="text: formNum"></span></span>
         </p>
         <p>Sample rate (Hz):
            <select data-bind="options: $parent.sampleRate, value: selectedSampleRate"></select>
         </p>
         <p>TDM channels per line:
            <select data-bind="options: tdmChans, value: selectedTdmchan"></select>
         </p>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <button data-bind="click: addForm">Add &lt;srate&gt; element</button>
   <button data-bind="click: removeForm">Remove</button>
   <hr/>
   <ul data-bind="foreach: forms">
      <li>
         <!-- render the json -->
         <p class="code">&lt;srate id="<span data-bind="text: formNum"></span>"&gt;
            <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;sample_rate&gt;<span data-bind="text: selectedSampleRate"></span>&lt;&#47;sample_rate&gt;
            <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;tdm_chan&gt;<span data-bind="text: selectedTdmchan"></span>&lt;&#47;tdm_chan&gt;
            <br/>
         </p>
      </li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

**JS code:**

```
window.onload = startKnockout;
var formNum;
var i = -1;    

function Form() {
    var self = this;

    // Declare observables
    self.selectedSampleRate = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTdmchan = ko.observable();
    self.formNum = ko.observable();

    // Define controls
    self.tdmChans = ko.computed(function() {
        if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 44100 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 48000) {
            return ['2', '4', '8', '16'];
        } else if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 88200 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 96000) {
            return ['2', '4', '8'];
        } else if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 176400 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 192000) {
            return ['2', '4'];
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }, self);
    i++;
    self.formNum = i;
}

var Vm = function() {
    var self = this;
    var item = 0;

    self.forms = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.forms.push(new Form());
    item++;
    self.addForm = function() {
        if (i < 5) {
            self.forms.push(new Form());
            item++;

        } else {
            alert("Can't have more than 6 <srate> elements!")
        }
    };
    self.removeForm = function() {
        if (item > 1) {
            self.forms.splice(item - 1, 1);
            item--;
            i--;
        } else {
            alert("Must have at least one <srate> element!")
        }
    };

    self.sampleRate = ko.observableArray(['192000', '176400', '96000', '88200', '48000', '44100']);
    return self;
}

// Activates knockout.js
function startKnockout() {
    ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/martinbooth/x3cg131g/1/

importantly, compute the available samples rates based on what has been selected in other forms:

```
self.sampleRates = ko.computed(function(){
    var formsValue = forms(),
        availableSampleRates = ko.utils.arrayFilter(allSampleRates, function(sampleRate){
            return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(formsValue, function(form){
                return form != self && form.selectedSampleRate() === sampleRate;
            });
    });

    return availableSampleRates;
});
```